# different color of framenumber during overlays

Tags: beamer, color

I want to have a different color (lets say gray) for the framenumber during the slides produced by overlays than the framenumber on the final slide (of each frame) (lets say black)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Number in gray

\only<2>{Number not in gray, but in black}

\insertframenumber{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if the current slide is the last slide of the frame by comparing `\thepage` with `\insertframeendpage`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \ifnum\thepage=\insertframeendpage%
        \color{red}%
    \else%
        \color{blue}%
    \fi%
    \insertframenumber%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Number in gray

\only<2>{Number not in gray, but in black}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```